# Best STL container for fast lookups

Tags: c++, collections, stl

I need to store a list of integers, and very quickly determine if an integer is already in the list. No duplicates will be stored.

I won't be inserting or deleting any values, but I will be appending values (which might be implemented as inserting).

What is the best STL container class for this? I found `std::multimap` on Google, but I that seems to require a key/value pair, which I don't have.

I'm fairly new to STL. Can I get some recommendations?

Comment: For future references, [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) is a list of all standard containers.

Comment: `unordered_set<int>`

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Thanks for that. But I'm not clear which have the fastest lookup. `set` seems like a possibility. But again, I'm not sure I'm clear on how fast.

Comment: Is there some range of values the integers will be falling in?

Comment: You have given complexity. but timing requires as usual to benchmark to your usage. (linear search might be faster than binary search with cache usage, branch prediction, ...).

Comment: Probably `std::unordered_set`, but also depends a lot on the integers being inserted. If there are a lot of hash collisions you may find yourself with effectively a linked list.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: The integers are IDs in a database. So not likely to exceed a thousand or so, but could.

Comment: @user4581301: Well, my values will have no duplicates. I don't know how the containers compute hashes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985572/which-is-the-fastest-stl-container-for-find  Pretty much spells out the costs of each.

Comment: What do you mean by "append" vs "insert"? That the new element is always larger than all the existing ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::unordered_set<int>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) is a good choice for keeping track of duplicates of `int`s, since both insertion and lookup can be achieved in constant time on average.

---

#### Insertion

Inserting a new `int` into the collection can be achieved with the [`insert()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/insert) member function:

```
std::unordered_set<int> s;
s.insert(7);
```

#### Lookup

Checking whether a given `int` is present in the collection can be done with the [`find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/find) member function:

```
bool is_present(const std::unordered_set<int>& s, int value) {
   return s.find(value) != s.end();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of a map, you can use a set when the value and the key aren't separate.

Instead of a multiset/-map, you can use the non-multi version which doesn't store duplicates.

Instead of a set, you have the `std::unordered_set` as an alternative. It may be faster for your use case.

There are other, less generic, data structures that can be used to represent sets of integers, and some of those may be more efficient depending on the use case. But those other data structures aren't necessarily provided for you by the standard library.

> But I'm not clear which have the fastest lookup.

Unordered set has better asymptotic complexity for lookups than the ordered one. Whether it is faster for your use case, you can find out by measuring.

> not likely to exceed a thousand or so

In that case, asymptotic complexity is not necessarily relevant.

Especially for small-ish sets like this, a sorted vector can be quite efficient. Given that you *"won't be inserting or deleting any values"*, the vector shouldn't have significant downsides either. The standard library doesn't provide a set container implemented internally using a sorted vector, but it does provide a vector container as well as all necessary algorithms.

> I don't know how the containers compute hashes.

You can provide a hash function for the unordered container. By default it uses `std::hash`. `std::hash` uses an implementation defined hash function.